# Analyzing GDELT GKG with Google BigQuery: the amount of records added daily decrease over time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Google BigQuery to explore GDELT's Global Knowledge Graph (GKG).

Summarizing by day, I found a curious progression: over time, the daily amount of captured media articles *decreases*, instead of increasing (as one would assume given the explosion of online news)

My results look like this:

[image: GDELT's GKG: records per day]

Is this something that others can corroborate? Could this be explained by virtue of GDELT adding new sources all the time, which means that there's a significant amount of backlog articles to capture, so when the number of sources stabilize only a small delta of current articles is captured daily thus making the daily count of "new" articles decrease?

I've also isolated GKG records where the source ("SourceCommonName") matches a specific country, joining against the geographic lookup table from https://blog.gdeltproject.org/mapping-the-media-a-geographic-lookup-of-gdelts-sources/

Since I'm researching Argentine media, I isolated records from Argentina sources, and got similar results: the daily progression also shows a clearly decreasing slope:

[image: GDELT's GKG: records per day - Argentina sources]

Here's the query I've used to count GKG records per day:

```
SELECT 
   `DATE`, 
   count(*) AS `n`
FROM (
   SELECT DIV(`DATE`, 1000000) AS `DATE`
   FROM (
      SELECT `DATE`
      FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg`)
   )
GROUP BY `DATE`
```

Any insights will be appreciated!